# get pid of a dead process C

Tags: signals

```
signal(SIGCHLD , del_pid);
```

Hello, i'm using that code in C to delete a pid in an array, but when my process dies, my function del_pid always receive 17 as pid, what's the problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> my function `del_pid` always receive 17 as `pid`.

No, the signal handler is not given the *PID* as an argument, since you can easily get that with a call to `getpid()` and, for a given process, this never changes.

The value that's delivered to the signal handler is `signum`, the signal *number,* as per the [docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html). This allows you to use the same signal handler for multiple signals and decide what to do based on which one was received (such as handling `SIGTERM`, `SIGQUIT` and `SIGINT` similarly).

If you look at the [Linux signal list](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/programming/linux_pgsignals.html), you can indeed see that `SIGCHLD` is `17`, which is what you're getting in your handler.